# Is it possible to display SVG in Qt(5.3) TextEdit without loosing quality?

Tags: image, qt, svg, qml, textedit

I have svg image with this attributes: `viewBox="0 0 100 100"`

This is basic code which I use for displaying svg:

```
Image{
  width: 50
  height: 50
  source: "test.svg"
}
```

and it's not ok because image is rasterized before resizing to width and height values(50,50).

This code works perfect on all resolution:

```
Image{
  width: 50
  height: 50
  sourceSize.width: width
  sourceSize.height: height
  source: "test.svg"
}
```

because image is drawn in exact dimensions which is needed!

Is it possible to get same functionality in a TextEdit where `<img>` tag is used?

```
<img src="test.svg" width="50" height="50">
```

This code doesn't work because sourceSize can't be set... and image is rasterized before resizing and displaying...

Maybe there is some other way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

The only solution is to provide the image size as part of the image url, and reimplement `QTextDocument::loadResource` or `QTextEdit::loadResource` in a derived class. Your image element would then look like:

```
<img src="test.svg?50x50" width="50" height="50" />
```

You can parse the url in your implementation of `loadResource`.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I don't belive it's possible in QML, and reimplement TextEdit in C i too much for me... The main goal is displaying some text and some inline images(like smileys in chat application). I use TextEdit because it can display RichText(html in this case), and that html normaly works in IE or FF browser - the svg looks perfect. Why it's not working in Qt? Is there any other way to mix text and images?

Comment: @DuhRobot It's not working because this is legacy widgets code that nobody bothered to maintain. You're more than welcome to submit the necessary changes on gerrit and contribute the needed changes to Qt. The "reimplementation" is of just one method, not of the entire class :)

Comment: Thank you @Kuba Ober. I need to resize my custom svg images depending on screen dpi. Maybe that will be posible to achieve with a new web engine in Qt 5.4. For now it seems that's not possible...easy way in QML.